# Mail failed to send 550 unknown host

Tags: dns, sendmail

Trying to send mail from my centOS 7 server but they are failing.

Below is an extract from the mail with what i think is the cause but im not sure how to fix.

I believe i have the correct setup in my hosts file but could be mistaken.

NOTE: I have substituted my email address for email@myaddress.com.

The maillog has stat=sent as well.

```
The original message was received at Tue, 29 Nov 2016 10:46:18 GMT
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<email@myaddress.com>
    (reason: 550 Host unknown)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
550 5.1.2 <email@myaddress.com>... Host unknown (Name server: myaddress.com: host not found)
```

Edit

```
#/usr/sbin/sendmail -d8.20 -bv email@myaddress.com  
Warning: OperatorChars is being redefined.  
         It should only be set before ruleset definitions.  
Warning: OperatorChars is being redefined.  
         It should only be set before ruleset definitions.  
Warning: OperatorChars is being redefined.  
         It should only be set before ruleset definitions.  
dns_getcanonname(myaddress.com, trymx=1)  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
dns_getcanonname: trying myaddress.com. (AAAA)  
    YES  
email@myaddress.com... deliverable: mailer local, user email
```

Comment: what happen on your server if you tries this `host -t MX myaddress.com` ? If you can't answer comment, just update your post. Also show us your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: You forgot to specify your MTA.

Comment: host -t MX myaddress.com    
myaddress.com mail is handled by 10 eu-smtp-inbound-1.mimecast.com.  
myaddress.com mail is handled by 20 eu-smtp-inbound-2.mimec

Comment: resolv.conf:  # Generated by NetworkManager
search localdomain
nameserver 172.16.213.2

Comment: Edit the question to add additional information. Don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working now. For the benefit of others this is what i did:

uninstalled sendmail and sendmail-cf so i could start fresh
yum remove sendmail sendmail-cf

install them fresh again
yum install sendmail sendmail-cf

edit /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
set the LOCAL_DOMAIN option to your machine hostname  LOCAL_DOMAIN(`example.com')dnl

next run
make -C /etc/mail
edit /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 hostname hostname.domainname
172.16.213.146(my internal ip) hostname hostname.domainname domainname

edit /etc/sysconfig/network HOSTNAME should equal your machine hostname

finally run
service sendmail restart

This is what worked for me on my vm server, there may be uneccassary steps here and i cant explain them but it made it work. Thanks for everyones input.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command below to see DNS queries issued by sendmail by sendmail.org/sendmail.com:
`/usr/sbin/sendmail -d8.20 -bv email@myaddress.com`

Execute the command as root if execution by non privileged user is inconclusive.